# Sage math repeat process

Tags: python, algorithm, math, primes, sage

Using `sage maths` I need to find the next three primes after 7.

My code currently is:

```
P = Primes()

P.next(7)
```

How would I get this to repeat to find the other 2 solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use a loop to scan your prime table.

```
P=Primes()
a=7
for i in range(3):
    a=P.next(a)
    print a
```

Answer (score 0):

a simple way is this:

```
START_PRIME = 7    
NUMBER_PRIMES = 3

for p in Primes():
     if p <= START_PRIME:
         continue
     ret.append(p)
     if len(ret) >= NUMBER_PRIMES:
         break
```

actually `Primes()` behaves like a list. once you known the index of your start prime (`3` in this case) you can get the following primes by:

```
p = Primes()
START_INDEX = 3
NUMBER_PRIMES = 3

p[START_INDEX+1:START_INDEX+1+NUMBER_PRIMES]
```

and in order to find the index i suggest you use `prime_range`. so again:

```
p_list = prime_range(100)

START_INDEX = p_list.index(7)
NUMBER_PRIMES = 3
p_list[START_INDEX+1:START_INDEX+1+NUMBER_PRIMES]
```